# Does it take time for Easy tables to create an API in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have recently started using easy tables within my Azure portal to create api's for tables that already exist in my database.  As we know Azure understands that if a table exists it simply creates the api for getting the json data from it, it doesn't recreate the table.

My question is does this process take various amounts of time?  Sometimes when I use easy tables it works perfectly and I can access the API and get data back (I use an application like Postman).  Other times I can create the table and when I query the the URI I get an empty array back `[]`.

At one stage I wasn't getting any data back, I was doing other tasks within Azure and all of a suddent I started getting data having changed nothing.  I add my tables from visual studio at the moment using the sql object explorer which is linked to my azure account.  I tested and every table I create can be seen and when you access that table in azure it returns data, so I know the data and table are there and azure can see the.

I can't see any information about it and I could just be being impatient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the plan your App Service is running on.  If the service is on a Shared or Free plan, then your service gets shut down after approximately 5 minutes of inactivity.  When you connect to your service again (via Postman or your mobile app), the service will be woken up and will do a cold start, which takes time.